# Error with comparing CGPoint using XCTAssertEqual in Xcode 5.1

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest

I just upgraded to XCode 5.1 and am seeing a compilation error in my unit tests for code like this:

```
CGPoint p1 = CGPointMake(1,2);
CGPoint p2 = CGPointMake(2,3);
XCTAssertEqual(p1, p2, @"Points not equal");
```

This is the error message:

```
Invalid operands to binary expression ('typeof (p1)' (aka 'struct CGPoint') and 'typeof (p2)' (aka 'struct CGPoint'))
```

The same code worked in previous versions of XCode. Is the code incorrect, or is this a bug in the latest XCode?

**Update**

The error is triggered by the `XCTAssertEqual` macro doing a != on the two variables. As these are structs this is not allowed. Did the macro change from 5.0 to 5.1, or did the compiler allow comparison of structs before?

**Update 2**

The code can be fixed by changing too

```
XCTAssertEqualObjects([NSValue valueWithCGPoint:p1],
                      [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:p2],
                      @"Points not equal");
```

I would still like to know what caused this to start failing. (Unfortunately the old version of xcode is removed by installing the new one).

Comment: The above test code (`XCTAssertEqual(p1, p2, @"Points not equal");
`) definitely compiles fine in Xcode 5.0.1 (5A2034a).

Comment: can you click through to the macro definition and see if it includes the != test?

Comment: In xcode 5.1 it has `if (a1value != a2value) {`

Comment: No, in 5.0.1, `XCTAssertEqual` evaluates to `_XCTPrimitiveAssertEqual`, which is not doing a `!=`. It's encoding the primitives into `NSValue`s via `value:withObjCType:`, then comparing via `isEqualToValue:`.

Comment: Another option would be to use something like `XCTAssertTrue( NSEqualPoints( NSPointFromCGPoint( p1 ), NSPointFromCGPoint( p2) ), @"Points not equal" );`

Comment: Want to post those as answers. It sounds like I should file a bug report with apple

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The functionally of this macro was changed in Xcode 5.1 to allow comparison of scalar values but removing support for nonscalar types like the struct CGPoint.

From the release notes
The XCTAssertEqual macro (formerly STAssertEquals using OCUnit) correctly compares scalar values of different types without casting, for example, int andNSInteger. It can no longer accept nonscalar types, such as structs, for comparison. (14435933)

Answer (score 6):

That test code:

```
XCTAssertEqual(p1, p2, @"Points not equal"); )
```

...definitely compiles fine in Xcode 5.0.1 (5A2034a). In 5.0.1, `XCTAssertEqual` evaluates to `_XCTPrimitiveAssertEqual`, which is not doing a `!=`. It's encoding the primitives into `NSValue`s via `value:withObjCType:`, then comparing via `isEqualToValue:`.

Another option would be to use something like:

```
XCTAssertTrue( NSEqualPoints( NSPointFromCGPoint( p1 ), NSPointFromCGPoint( p2) ), 
    @"Points not equal" );
```

Comment: Simpler option:  `XCTAssertTrue(CGPointEqualToPoint(p1, p2), @"Points not equal");`